# How do I determine the position/width/height of a monitor in a multi-monitor setup in C#.NET?

Tags: c#, multiscreen

I'm creating a Unity application that needs to span across multiple monitors, but I need to determine where each monitor lies on the overall desktop in order to determine which monitors need to display which camera views.

Let's say I have 5 monitors arranged side-by-side, where the numbers are (going from left to right) #3,#4,#2,#1,#5. Each monitor has a resolution of 1920 x 1080.

Based upon this, I want to write a method that accepts the monitor's number and spits out its position, width and height on the screen. In the above example, #1 would be positioned at 5760,0 as it is the 4th monitor from the right.

Comment: Hard to see a concrete question.  Consider the Screen class.

Comment: @HansPassant Basically, I want to know how I can get the position and resolution of a monitor given its number (as displayed in the control panel).

Comment: Yes, the Screen class tells you this.  Have you tried it?  What did not work when you did?

Comment: @HansPassant Great answer! Unfortunately it's not available in Unity, but still useful in case anybody needs this for a standard C#.NET application!

Comment: @HansPassant Please could you post your first comment as an answer.  It's just that I've found a workaround that still uses the Screen class, and I want to give credit where it's due!